# How would you derive these properties using component form?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm currently looking over lecture notes and am looking at the following properties:
[image: properties]

Can anyone explain how they might be derived using component form?

Comment: Are the symbols $\underline a, \underline b$ used to denote 3D vectors?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what "component form" means.Do you mean by examining the individual co-ordinates of the vectors?

Comment: @user2910074 I hope my answer is useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'll show how some of them can be done, first let $e_1=(1,0,0),\ e_2=(0,1,0),\ e_3=(0,0,1)$, then if we let $\underline a=\sum_{n=1}^3 a_n(t)e_n$ and $\underline b=\sum_{n=1}^3 b_n(t)e_n$ we can show that

$$\begin{align}
\frac d{dt}(\underline a+\underline b) &= \frac d{dt}\{\sum_{n=1}^3 (a_n(t)+b_n(t))e_n\} \\
&= \frac d{dt}(\sum_{n=1}^3 a_n(t)e_n+\sum_{n=1}^3 b_n(t)e_n) \\
&= \frac d{dt}\sum_{n=1}^3 a_n(t)e_n+\frac d{dt}\sum_{n=1}^3 b_n(t)e_n \\
&= \frac {d\underline a}{dt}+\frac {d\underline b}{dt}
\end{align}$$

For the second equality, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac d{dt}(\lambda(t)\underline a) &= \frac d{dt}\sum_{n=1}^3(\lambda(t)a_n(t))e_n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^3\frac d{dt}(\lambda(t)a_n(t))e_n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^3\left((\frac d{dt}\lambda(t))a_n(t)+
\lambda(t)(\frac d{dt}a_n(t))\right)e_n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^3(\frac d{dt}\lambda(t))a_n(t)e_n+\sum_{n=1}^3
\lambda(t)(\frac d{dt}a_n(t))e_n \\
&=(\frac d{dt}\lambda(t))\sum_{n=1}^3a_n(t)e_n+\lambda(t)\sum_{n=1}^3
(\frac d{dt}a_n(t))e_n \\
&=\frac {d\lambda(t)}{dt}\underline a+\lambda(t)\frac {d\underline a}{dt}
\end{align}$$

The rest are similar, just expand the sum and use the product law. You should be able to do it yourself :)